# Angular 4, Phonegap icons Windows Phone 10

Tags: angular, cordova, windows-phone, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have project in Angular 4 + Phonegap. When I build the project online with `/build.phonegap.com`, the website shows the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\project\res\icons\windows'
   at Error (native)
   at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18)
   at C:\project\cordova\lib\prepare.js:390:33
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at mapImageResources (C:\project\cordova\lib\prepare.js:378:12)
   at copyImages (C:\project\cordova\lib\prepare.js:442:23)
   at C:\project\cordova\lib\prepare.js:615:9
   at _fulfilled (C:\project\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\project\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\project\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
```

I took icons from web generator. I've tried few generators. I use a relative path, so  I don't know from where the path `C:\project\res\icons\windows` comes.